# Comparing growth of rates for small time series measurements before and after intervention in R

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, intervention-analysis

I have 2 small time series where I calculate success rates before and after intervention.

*Experiment 1*

```
df <- data.frame(time = 1:8, 
                 N = c(0, 2, 6, 12, 24, 31, 39, 35),
                 Total = c( 19, 17, 25, 36, 53, 65, 58, 48), 
                 intervention = rep(c(0,1), each=4) )
df$P <- df$N / df$Total * 100
```

[image]

*Experiment 2:*

```
df <- data.frame(time = 1:8, 
                 N = c(0, 0,  0, 0, 5, 12,  13, 10),
                 Total = c( 15, 10,  21, 26, 43, 51,  39, 36), 
                 intervention = rep(c(0,1), each=4) )


df$P <- df$N / df$Total * 100
```

[image]

**Question:** What would be the appropriate statistical analysis in this case to estimate if the intervention played a significant role in performance change rate? Is it possible to make any reasonable conclusion with these many data points?

Comment: I've seen analyses of time series with an intervention under the term [interrupted time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupted_time_series) analysis. A good starting point is the tutorial by [Bernal et al. (2016)](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/46/1/348/2622842).